# How to show users currently logged in to site

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I have a website that has members log in. I store the members/users in a users table in a MySQL database. How can i on my website show a table with all the users currently logged in. The way i wanted to do it is have an extra table in the database that would store the currently logged in users but i am not allowed to do that. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Any help or links would be much appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I was told i am not allowed to change the database, cause that is what i first thought of doing, so i cannot add a column called lastactivitydate to the users table.

Comment: You need a way to define a logged in user. The easiest way for this is "a user that has done any activity for the last _n_ minutes". If you cannot incorporate that or a similar logic in your data model because you are not allowed to change it, you cannot complete this task.

Answer (score 1):

you can have an extra column "Active" that will be updated everytime a user logs in.
you can just take a count of that when you need online users.

Comment: Who will put the 'active' value back to inactive? I suggest using a 'last active' column and comparing the current time to that. Users that didn't explicitly logout and are inactive for, say, 5 minutes are considered not logged on.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a column in your members table called something like `last_login_time`. Then to know which users are currently logged in you can simply check that column for some actual period of time, like this

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `last_login_time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

> create a column in member table as **login_time** and **logout_time** use query to display logged in user

```
SELECT `user_name` From `table_name` WHERE `login_time` > `logout_time`
```